# What syntax am I using incorrectly for this segment of code?

Tags: python

I am completing an exercise for an online class I am auditing (it isn't graded, and I don't have feedback). I'm really new to programming and have tried a bunch of different things but it never gets past the first line.

Here's the setup:

```
hot = True
cold = False
morning = True
evening = False
night = False
```

These are the instructions:

```
#You may modify the lines of code above, but don't move them!
#When you Submit your code, we'll change these lines to
#assign different values to the variables.

#Write a program that will recommend a meal based on the
#current weather and time of day. Specifically, the program
#should recommend:
#
# - soup if it's cold and either evening or night
# - a biscuit if it's morning and cold
# - cereal if it's morning and hot, or whenever the time is
#   night
# - pizza whenever it's either evening or night
#
#Write some code below that will print four lines, one for
#each of the four meals. The lines should look like this:
#
#Soup: False
#Biscuit: False
#Cereal: True
#Pizza: False
#
#The values (True and False) will differ based on the
#values assigned to hot, cold, morning, evening, and night
#at the start of the program.
```

And this is the code I came up with:

```
if cold and (evening or night)
    print("Soup")
if morning and cold
    print ("Biscuit")
if (morning and hot) or night
    print("Cereal")
if evening or night
    print("Pizza")
```

I get a SyntaxError. What am I doing wrong?
I feel stupid asking about this (probably really simple) bit of code, but I've tried a bunch of different variations, and cannot get it right.

Comment: Look up  on how to use an if condition in python. Perhaps: https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html

Comment: You forget to add `:`  after each if. So you should write `if cold and (evening or night):` and so forth

Comment: If you make your question title more specific, you are more likely to get more upvotes.

Answer (score 3):

you're using the `if` statement wrong.

The `if` statment in `python` is followed bu **:**

so you need to correct it as follows:

```
hot = True
cold = False
morning = True
evening = False
night = False

if cold and (evening or night):
    print("Soup")
if morning and cold:
    print ("Biscuit")
if (morning and hot) or night:
    print("Cereal")
if evening or night:
    print("Pizza")
```

You can read about how to appropriately use `if` in python in the following [link](http://anh.cs.luc.edu/handsonPythonTutorial/ifstatements.html)

*Note*

I'm not sure what you are trying to accomplish with those multiple `if`'s but consider using `if-elif-else` ladder